# Can you write your whole existing filesystem to an image?

Tags: ramdisk

I'm reading about filesystems for embedded linux. If you're using a ramdisk, how its supposed to work is a compressed image of the filesystem is kept in the boot partition, and is copied into the root partition at startup. This is supposed to be a relatively efficient way to do things, which is good for embedded systems, but the problem is that changes aren't persistent. You cant save a file that will be there after a reboot.

So I'm wondering if a way around this would just be to replace the compressed filesystem image? Like at shutdown, take your existing filesystem, with whatever changes are there, and make that to a new image to put in the boot partition? That way the next time you start up all the files you put there will be restored along with the core filesystem.

Comment: okay, If you have write ability to write the ramdisk image could you just mount that location in linux and just save your files there.

Comment: If the media the ramdisk image is on has room. Create a new partition and extract the image to it and change your root to that new partition. Now you no longer have a read only file system, albeit a little slower on the read.